# SQL - add records to temp table until order is fulfilled

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What would be some ways to tackle this scenario?  I want to select just enough records from table b to support table a and I want to use oldest to newest from table b.

**table a:**

```
orderNum  partNum    quantity     ship date 
-----------------------------------------------
1         XYZ              15     7/1/2014
2         XYZ              15     8/1/2014
```

**table b:**

```
lotID     partNum    quantity     dateEnt
-----------------------------------------------
1         XYZ              10     1/1/2014
2         XYZ              10     2/1/2014
3         XYZ              10     3/1/2014
```

**results:**

```
orderNum  partNum     quantity    lotID     lotQuantity
--------------------------------------------------------
1         XYZ               15    1                  10
1         XYZ               15    2                   5
2         XYZ               15    2                   5
2         XYZ               15    3                  10
```

This is what i've tried

```
select orderNum,case when lotQty < (orderQty - prevLotQty) then lotQty else orderQty -   prevLotQty end as needed,lotID from
(select top 1000 orderNum,tv.orderQty,lotQty,
        prevIQty = isNull((select sum(qty) from tableB where partnum = tb.partNum and dateent < tb.dateEnt),0)
        from tableA as ta inner join tableB as tb on ta.partNum = tableB.partNum
        where tablB.qty > 0 order by dateEnt) as baseQry
where orderQty - prevLotQty > 0
```

This works for one order, but reuses the same records from table b if there are more orders on the same part.

Comment: Show us what you've tried please.

Comment: Just enough to satisfy what criteria?

Comment: what happens with quantity in table b? is updated to zero each row?

Comment: So you need a store procedure that uses up the lot's until the order is fully filled. Needs some TSQL computing. But can you explain why do that on SQL itself? since this is businesses logic? Or better ask do you have any other way of doing this? Is your SQL server an Enterprise edition? Because otherwise you can have balancing issues if this does not happen over night or so

Comment: @JiggsJedi, I've tried keeping running totals but it kept reusing the same lots to support the order.

Comment: @Hogan order quantity

Comment: You've showed us the table data. Great. Could you show us the SQL that you tried, the output that you got using that SQL and the desired output?

Comment: @horaciux table b is not updated.

Comment: if you say table b will not be updated how can you then keep track of what is being used and what not? you planning to use an extra table for that?

Comment: @Jester I was planning to use a temporary table.  The sql in my edit would add to this table.  I probably just need to join the temp table and test some values, but is this the most suitable method?

Comment: What programing language are you using to make the business logic?

Comment: @Jester c#.  Do you think it would be more efficient in business logic?  I wouldn't have a problem writing that.  I just assumed it would be faster in sql.

Comment: from my experience no since if you gonna have a large data set to process cursors and stuff are slow in tSQL and are putting huge strain on the server and if you don't have an Enterprise grade server you have no way of balancing that witch means that that can cause other users to have timeout problems if they are running query's at the same time

Comment: Since you want update the row on the fly an use that in the in same statement I would do that in .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my oppinion would be better to solve that on the buisness logic side but if you really whant to do it on the server side for some reason (nightjob,...) then something like this script. But keep in mind the preformance problems and other things I pointed out in comments. For a C# based solution look the Blam's answer here is the sql aproach to that

```
create table tabA (orderNum Numeric(1), partNum varchar(3), quntity numeric(2), shipdate datetime)
create table tabB (lotID Numeric(1), partNum varchar(3), quntity numeric(2), dateEnt datetime)

create table tabC (orderNum Numeric(1), partNum varchar(3), quntity numeric(2), lotID Numeric(1), lotQuntity numeric(2))

insert into tabA values(1,'XYZ',15,'20140107'),
                        (2,'XYZ',15,'20140107')

insert into tabB values(1,'XYZ',10,'20140101'),
                        (2,'XYZ',10,'20140102'),
                        (3,'XYZ',10,'20140103')

select * into #tabB1 from tabB

declare @lnOrderNum numeric(1), @lcPartNum varchar(3), @ldShipdate datetime, @lnQuntity numeric(2)
declare @lnLotID numeric(1), @lcPartNum1 varchar(3), @ldEntdate datetime, @lnQuntity1 numeric(2), 
        @lnQuntity2 numeric(2), @lnQuntity3 numeric(2)
declare cur_a cursor for
select * 
from tabA
order by shipdate


open cur_a
fetch next from cur_a into @lnOrderNum, @lcPartNum,@lnQuntity, @ldShipdate
while @@Fetch_status=0
BEGIN

    SET @lnQuntity3 = @lnQuntity
    while @lnQuntity > 0
    BEGIN
        select top 1 lotID, partNum, quntity, dateEnt into #tmpB1
        from #tabB1
        where quntity > 0
        order by dateEnt

        set @lnLotID = (select top 1 lotId from #tmpB1 )
        set @lcPartNum1 = (select top 1 partNum from #tmpB1 )
        set @ldEntdate = (select top 1 dateEnt from #tmpB1 )
        set @lnQuntity1 = (select top 1 quntity from #tmpB1 )




        IF @lnQuntity1 >= @lnQuntity
        BEGIN
            SET @lnQuntity2 = 0
            insert into tabC values(@lnOrderNum,@lcPartNum,@lnQuntity3,@lnLotID,@lnQuntity)
            update #tabB1 
                set quntity = @lnQuntity1 - @lnQuntity
                where lotId = @lnLotID and partNum = @lcPartNum1 and dateEnt = @ldEntdate

            drop table #tmpB1
            SET @lnQuntity = @lnQuntity2
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @lnQuntity2 = @lnQuntity - @lnQuntity1
            insert into tabC values(@lnOrderNum,@lcPartNum,@lnQuntity3,@lnLotID,@lnQuntity1)
            update #tabB1 
                set quntity = 0
                where lotId = @lnLotID and partNum = @lcPartNum1 and dateEnt = @ldEntdate

            drop table #tmpB1
            SET @lnQuntity = @lnQuntity2
        END
    END
    fetch next from cur_a into @lnOrderNum, @lcPartNum,@lnQuntity, @ldShipdate
END

close cur_a
deallocate cur_a

drop table #tabB1

drop table tabA
drop table tabB
SELECT * FROM TABC
drop table tabC
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll take your advice and move this out of SQL

Answer (score 1):

This is just an outline but it is the basic logic
SqlDataReader is very efficient so this will be very efficient

```
SqlDatadeader rdrOrderNum -- proper sort 
SqlDatadeader rdrLotID -- proper sort

orderNum = null;
quantityNeed;
quantityLeft = 0;
lotID = null;

while(rdrOrderNum.Read());
{
   orderrNum = rdrOrderNum.GetInt32(0);
   quantityNeed = rdrOrderNum.GetInt32(2);
   if (quantityNeed <= quantityLeft)
   {
      quantityLeft -= quantityNeed;
      continue;
   }
   quantityNeed -= quantityLeft;
   while(quantityNeed > 0)
   {
      if(!rdrLotID.HasRows()) exit;
      rdrLotID.Read();
      lotID = rdrLotID.GetInt32(0);
      int quantityThis = rdrLotID.GetInt32(1);
      if (quantityNeed  >  quantityThis )
      {
          quatityNeed -= quantityThis;
          quantityLeft = 0;
          continue;
      }
      else 
      {
          quantityLeft = quantityThis - quantityNeed;
          quantityNeed = 0;
          break;
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample.  As you and @Jester pointed out, this looks better suited in the code.

Comment: So you asked how to tackle this.  You are using this.  But this is not the accepted solution.  Interesting.